# Redirect the user to the log-in page after session expired in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

## Goal

I'm trying to redirect my user to my login page as soon as their session expired or log-out.

Example: if they log-out, and try to click on any link, they should get redirected to the log-in page.

---

I have my log-in route declared like this

```
Route::get('/',['as' => 'login', 'uses'=>'AuthController@getSignIn']);
```

---

Then, I tried to configure it in `config/session.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => true,
'expired-session-redirect' => url('/')
```

---

As soon as my user session is expired, I click on other linked, I didn't get redirect to my log-in page ?

It crashed and return the white empty page:

[image]

What else do I need to do to achieve something like that ?

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think the url() function will work in a config file.

Answer (score 3):

For redirecting users who aren't signed in, you can add the auth middleware to any routes that you don't want to allow signed out users to visit. More info on [Laravel middleware documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware).

For a single route:

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');
```

For a route group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    //
});
```

It depends on which version of Laravel you're using to determine how to set where the user is redirected to.